# using java to manipulate images

Tags: java

I did a successful application that takes a screenshot of a pc in a local network, the image is saved on a specific path on the computer, and then it is send via output streams to another computer.
However, the image is still on the pc.
Is there any function in java that deletes the image created after it is send ?

Comment: What object type are you using to house the image?

Answer (score 1):

After the image is sent, surely calling the [file.delete()](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-delete-file-in-java/) method would work fine, to remove the image from the PC who's screen you just captured.

Comment: Please mark it as the correct answer, so people know the question is closed.